# viewpager automatically scroll too fast

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` which has 4 pages and I want it scroll automatically.

What I am doing is  `viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);` bound with a `TimerTask` where `index` is a precomputed integer.

The logic works fine but when it scroll (triggered by `setCurrentImte`) the animation is too fast.

How can I control the scroll speed of it? Please note I am talking about the scrolling animation speed, instead of the interval of 2 successive scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) instead? A ViewFlipper has built in functionality to handle auto-scrolling between views, which means you can dump the timer. Also, it implements [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html) which gives you full control over the animations. It is relatively simple to create custom animations, and you have control over the time it takes to animate. A simple tutorial for a slide animation can be found [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-dog-limps-into-a-saloon-a-tutorial-on-androids-viewflipper-widget/634). Take note of the duration attribute of the animation xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) doesn't provide such an API. I would suggest to do any of the following:

- Take VieWPager code (it's under Your android sdk extras folder) and twek it the way you need (e.g. add necessary API). Now it seems to use internal constant (`MAX_SETTLE_DURATION`);
- Intercept touches by yourself and call [fakeDragBy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#fakeDragBy%28float%29) (not sure if its what You're looking for);

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this? Use a value animator to animate the scroll values, then update the positioning so the fragment loading is correctly handled. Works fine for me :).

```
if(pager != null){
        ValueAnimator scrollAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(pager.getScrollX(), pager.getScrollX()+2560);
        final int virtualPage = pager.getCurrentItem();
        scrollAnimator.setDuration(1000);
        scrollAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                pager.setScrollX((Integer)animation.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });
        scrollAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                pager.setCurrentVirtualItem(virtualPage, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        scrollAnimator.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement on an app i am developing and my solution was this.

```
    Observable.range(1, vpAdapter.getCount() - 1)
            .concatMap(i-> Observable.just(i).delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(integer -> {
                currentAutoPage = integer;

                binding.vpTour.beginFakeDrag();
                lastFakeDrag = 0;
                ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, binding.vpTour.getWidth());
                va.setDuration(1000);
                va.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
                    if (binding.vpTour.isFakeDragging()) {
                        int animProgress = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        binding.vpTour.fakeDragBy(lastFakeDrag - animProgress);
                        lastFakeDrag = animProgress;
                    }
                });
                va.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        if (binding.vpTour.isFakeDragging()) {
                            binding.vpTour.endFakeDrag();
                        }
                    }
                });
                va.start();
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> {
                if (autoPageChangeDisposable != null && !autoPageChangeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
                    autoPageChangeDisposable.dispose();
                }
            });
```

In case you also want to stop the automatic swiping when user manually changes the page than just get the disposable from this code that i wrote, like this : "Disposable autoPageChangeDisposable = Observable.range(1, vpAdapter...." and than register and OnPageChangedListener and do this :

```
        vpTour.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position != currentAutoPage) {
                    if (autoPageChangeDisposable != null && !autoPageChangeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
                        autoPageChangeDisposable.dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```